# Why can't I update body_html from invoice mail template?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

So I've been asked to change body_html from invoice mail template. I've always made changes to this model through data xml file, so as usual I made this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">

            <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
                <value eval="[('module', '=', 'account'), ('name', '=', 'email_template_edi_invoice')]"/>
            </function>

            <value eval="{'noupdate': False}"/>
        </function>

        <record id="account.email_template_edi_invoice" model="mail.template">
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
        Dear ${object.approver.name}
        <br /><br />
        We need your aprobation for ${object.name}, fromn ${object.company_id.name}
        <br /><br />
        Please, check before everything is in order.
    </p>
</div>
            </field>
        </record>

        <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">

            <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
                <value eval="[('module', '=', 'account'), ('name', '=', 'email_template_edi_invoice')]"/>
            </function>

            <value eval="{'noupdate': True}"/>
        </function>
</odoo>
```

Before and after the real change, I've update the 'noupdate' value to False, in order to apply changes, and then back to True. This, because the original template, from *account* module, has the  tag.

After upgrading my custom module, the template body didn't change. I decided to try changing the name value, so I put this on my file:
(I've skipped the noupdate changes, in order to make it more simple)

```
<record id="account.email_template_edi_invoice" model="mail.template">
                    <field name="name">Invoice: Send by email (testing if this changes)</field> <!-- Here I put this to check if it changes -->
                    <field name="body_html" type="html">
        <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
                Dear ${object.approver.name}
                <br /><br />
                We need your aprobation for ${object.name}, fromn ${object.company_id.name}
                <br /><br />
                Please, check before everything is in order.
            </p>
        </div>
                    </field>
                </record>
```

With this, the name changed, but body still didn't get the changes applied. Is this a restriction from Odoo for changing native templates or something?
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Do you have more than one language active? Because the body_html field is translatable.

Comment: only one language active. Why?

Comment: Could have been a problem.

Comment: You need to set `no_update=False` for this `account.email_template_edi_invoice` email template id.

Comment: I did, it's in the question